# Rails controller rescue exception in `lib` directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception

I'm using a wrapper around a Wikipedia OmniAuth gem in my Devise initializer that is periodically throwing `JWT::DecodeErrors`. I'm trying to handle these errors with a custom error message, rather than throwing a 500. (Stick with me here.)

In my Devise initializer, I set up the strategy as such:

```
  config.omniauth :mediawiki,
                  Figaro.env.wikipedia_token,
                  Figaro.env.wikipedia_secret,
                  strategy_class: CustomStrategy,
                  client_options: {
                    site: "https://#{Figaro.env.wiki_language}.wikipedia.org"
                  }
```

My `CustomStrategy` inherits from the default MediaWiki strategy and adds some data to the `request` object to check for it later in the `ErrorsController`:

```
# lib/custom_strategy.rb

class LoginError < StandardError; end

class CustomStrategy < OmniAuth::Strategies::Mediawiki
  def parse_info(jwt_data)
    begin
      super
    rescue JWT::DecodeError
      request.env['JWT_ERROR'] = true
      request.env['JWT_DATA'] = jwt_data
      raise ::LoginError.new("\nA JWT::DecodeError occurred. Here is the web token data:\n#{jwt_data.body.inspect}")
    end
  end

end
```

So here I try to catch the `JWT::DecodeError` by raising a `LoginError` that I'm hoping to catch in my controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from StandardError, with: :handle_login_error
  ...
  protected
  def handle_login_error
    redirect_to errors_login_error_path
  end
end
```

The problem is that `rescue_from` [only handles exceptions thrown in the controller](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html).

Since this exception is thrown in my strategy, I don't have the opportunity to rescue it, and Rails just treats it as a `500`:

```
[2016-01-26 12:10:02.183 FATAL] StandardError (
A JWT::DecodeError occurred. Here is the web token data:
"{\"error\":\"mwoauthdatastore-access-token-not-found\",\"message\":\"No approved grant was found for that authorization token.\"}"):
  lib/custom_strategy.rb:9:in `rescue in parse_info'
  lib/custom_strategy.rb:6:in `parse_info'
[2016-01-26 12:10:02.251 INFO ] Processing by ErrorsController#internal_server_error as HTML
[2016-01-26 12:10:02.251 INFO ] Parameters: {"oauth_verifier"=>"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "oauth_token"=>"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"}
[2016-01-26 12:10:02.971 INFO ] Rendered errors/internal_server_error.html.erb within layouts/application (3.8ms)
[2016-01-26 12:10:03.204 INFO ] Rendered shared/_head.html.haml (10.1ms)
[2016-01-26 12:10:03.215 INFO ] Rendered shared/_nav.html.haml (9.7ms)
[2016-01-26 12:10:03.218 INFO ] Rendered shared/_foot.html.haml (2.3ms)
[2016-01-26 12:10:03.219 INFO ] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 967ms (Views: 265.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

So here, Rails treats it as a `500`, and I'm using [custom error pages](https://wearestac.com/blog/dynamic-error-pages-in-rails), not the Rails defaults.

For reference, here's my `ErrorsController`:

```
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :json

  def file_not_found
    render status: 404
  end

  def unprocessable
    render status: 422
  end

  def internal_server_error
    if request.env['JWT_ERROR']
      return login_error
    end
    render status: 500
  end

  def incorrect_passcode
    render status: 401
  end

  def login_error
    #return render status: 599
  end
end
```

What's the best way to handle this exception that happens in the `jwt-ruby` gem, which is a dependency of the `oauth-mediawiki` gem that I'm wrapping with a custom strategy that hopes to catch the `JWT::DecodeError` and handle it within my app? If this specific error arises, I want to render a special view, not just the 500 view.

## Edit 2: Further Articulation of the Problem

The problem is that I can't figure out a way to rescue the exception I've rescued and re-raised (`JWT::DecodeError`) in a way that allows me to render a custom view. As you can see from the log above, it just renders `ErrorsContoller#internal_server_error`.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is here?

Comment: @MichalSzyndel I've edited, hopefully that helps.

Comment: According to the docs, rescue_from should work if your code is executed from inside the controller. what's the full stack trace?

--come to think of it, maybe devise is catching the error for you, and renders 500.

Comment: So omniauth has a `OmniauthCallbacksController` and all errors inside devise are handled by it's `error` method which you can redefine. I think this should help

Comment: @MichalSzyndel Thanks. Tried `class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController` with an `error` method and stuck a `binding.pry` in there, but the code didn't get in there.

Comment: Looks like perhaps the [method is actually `failure`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview)? It also doesn't get in that method.

Comment: You're right, the method is called failure. Can you maybe get a full stack trace for this error. This is incredibly weird!

Comment: Yep, overwriting `failure` doesn't get in there. I suspect it's because it's not that there's an authentication failure, it's that it `raise`s an error before it gets there.

Comment: Right, but to get to 500 on the screen it HAS to go through some controller. I understand that 500 is returned through `ErrorsController#internal_server_error`?

Comment: @MichalSzyndel Correct. And it appears that if there's an exception anywhere, it renders `internal_server_error` at the end of the request cycle, even when it's rescued.

Comment: ok, can you then get the backtrace from the exception in `internal_server_error`?